# Recursive query with sum in 2 tables in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, sum, recursive-query

I have 2 tables and i need make a filter with pagination(limit and offset):

1. res_partner(id, name, parent_id) (250k rows)
2. account_invoice(id, amount_untaxed, partner_id, created_date) (700k row)

One partner can have many child, and many account invoice.

I need get all customer and the total invoice(sum of amount_untaxed) associate to him and their child on a time period.
Example:

**res_partner**

```
id ---   name ---   parent_id

1  ---    Jon 

2 ---      Snow ----   1

3  ---    Sam    -----   2
```

**account_invoice**

```
id     ---  amount_untaxed --- partner_id --- created_date

1 ------------------ 5.00 ---------1--------------'2015-09-29 21:37:39.427189'

2 ------------------ 7.00 ---------2--------------'2015-09-29 21:37:39.427189'

3 ------------------ 3.00 ---------3--------------'2015-09-29 21:37:39.427189'

4 ------------------ 9.00 ---------1--------------'2015-09-29 21:37:39.427189'
```

**I hope get:**

```
res_partner --- amount

1 -----------------24

2 -----------------10

3 -----------------3
```

Comment: Post any code you have written in an attempt to solve this. What effort(s) have you made? Where are you having problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive stored procedure to calculate value of each record.

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnTree(pid int)
> RETURNS numeric 
> AS $$
> DECLARE total numeric;
> BEGIN
>       WITH RECURSIVE tree(id, parent_id) AS 
>       (
>           SELECT id, parent_id 
>           FROM   res_partner 
>           WHERE  id = pid
>          UNION ALL
>           SELECT rp.id, rp.parent_id
>           FROM   res_partner rp 
>           JOIN   tree 
>           ON     rp.parent_id = tree.id
>       )
>       SELECT sum(amount_untaxed) into total
>       FROM   account_invoice ai
>       WHERE  partner_id in (SELECT id FROM tree);
>       RETURN total;
> END;
> $$ 
> LANGUAGE plpgsql;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select id, fnTree(id)
> from   res_partner;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | fntree
> -: | -----:
>  1 |  24.00
>  2 |  10.00
>  3 |   3.00
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=61c9307a425039d6075ad9d802efce0c)*

Comment: there is no point to use plpgsql here :-) You wrote it in plain SQL, so the function (if it's needed), can be just `language sql`.

Comment: I'm glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Here is way to do it with single SQL query, it uses `WITH RECURSIVE`, integer arrays, containment operator (`<@`), array concatination operator (`||`), and function that converts an array to a resultset, `unnest()`.

Inside `WITH RECURSIVE` we build "paths" for each record, and then calculate sum of amounts:

```
with recursive res(id, name, parent_id, path) as (
  select id, name, parent_id, array[id]
  from res_partner
  where parent_id is null

  union all

  select
    r2.id, r2.name, r2.parent_id, array[r2.id] || res.path
  from res_partner r2
  join res on res.id = r2.parent_id
)
select
  id as res_partner,
  --path, -- uncomment to debug
  (
    select sum(amount_untaxed)
    from account_invoice
    where
      partner_id in (
        select id
        from res r_in
        where r_out.path <@ r_in.path
      )
  ) as amount
from res r_out;
```